# Golang SIGSEGV on *second* call only

Tags: go, segmentation-fault

I have a method to quickly run a shell command:

```
func runcmd(c string, arg ...string) (string, string, string) {
    var o bytes.Buffer
    var e bytes.Buffer
    cmd := exec.Command(c, arg...)
    cmd.Stdout = &o
    cmd.Stderr = &e
    err := cmd.Run()
    return o.String(), e.String(), err.Error()
}
```

In my main have the following code:

```
func main() {

ver, _, exitcode := runcmd("rpm", "-q", "--queryformat", "%{VERSION}", "redhat-release")
var dist string
if exitcode != "" {
    ver, _, exitcode = runcmd("rpm", "-q", "--queryformat", "%{VERSION}", "centos-release")
    if exitcode != "" {
        fmt.Println("Unknown OS! Exiting without running!")
        os.Exit(3)
    }
    dist = "CentOS"
} else {
    dist = "Redhat/Redhat derivative"
}

fmt.Printf("System is %s %s.\n", dist, ver)
}
```

Running this produces a SIGSEGV. However, when I comment the second call to `runcmd` it runs as normal (returning `Unknown OS! Exiting without running! exit status 3`). I'm new to go so i don't really understand the nil pointer dereference  error to begin with, much less why it would only happen on the second call.

Comment: are you running CentOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always returning `err.Error()`, when there is no error (`err == nil`) this fails with nil pointer dereference.  You should do

```
func runcmd(c string, arg ...string) (string, string, error) {
  e bytes.Buffer
  cmd := exec.Command(c, arg...)
  cmd.Stdout = &o
  cmd.Stderr = &e
  err := cmd.Run()
  return o.String(), e.String(), err
}
```

and then

```
if exitcode != nil {
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of this line:

```
return o.String(), e.String(), err.Error()
```

If you are running CentOS then `err := cmd.Run()` will not return any error. Then `err` will be `nil`. But in `return` line you are returning `err.Error()`. You can not use access to a nil pointer. So, you are getting this error.